# Google Map not showing inside div liquid layout

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, html

I am trying to load a google map inside a page with a liquid layout.

This is the CSS of my **index.php** page:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    font: normal 13px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#div1 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #DDD;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#div2 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background: #AAA;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#div3 {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: #777;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

My map is contained in another page **map.php** Below is the content of my map.php page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
        body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
        #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // google map code
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

The map works just fine when I open it from map.php. But when I try to load it inside **div#2** of index.php, all I see is a gray area.

I do not know what's causing the problem. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
<?php
    // include db connect class
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
?>

        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // google map code with a query inside
        </script>

        <div id="map"></div>
```

The map is still not showing.

Comment: Explain how you're opening it within a `div` on another page?  The whole other page via ajax?  Show the code that loads the map into the `div`.

Comment: yes, i have a script in my index.php `$("#div2").load("map.php");`

Comment: That's your whole problem.  You can't fire another `body.onload` event that way so therefore you're never running the `initMap()` function.

Comment: I have this at script before my `</body>` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {    
    $("#div2").load("map.php");
   });
  </script>`

I included jquery inside my `<header` tag:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You should be putting all necessary code within your OP, **not** here in the comments.  And it does not matter _where_ you place `.load()`, you will not be able to force another `body.onload` event to occur.  The `onload` event already happened when you loaded `index.php`... you'll never fire another one no matter how much `ajax` you do.

Comment: I see. Sorry Im a newbie to ajax. How do I run the google map code without the body.onload event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here...

```
<body onload="initMap()">
```

You won't get this `body.onload` event if that page is loaded via `ajax`.  `body.onload` is only fired one time when the original page (`index.php`) is loaded or refreshed.  Any content loaded to this page with `ajax` will not get another `body.onload` event.  (That's one of the main points of `ajax`, to load content without a page refresh.)

To get around this, utilize [the `.load()` callback function](http://api.jquery.com/load/)... it fires *after* the `ajax` load is complete.

```
$("#div2").load('map.php', function() {
    // put init inside the callback
    initMap();
});
```

I would also re-factor the HTML of `map.php` so you don't end up with invalid HTML on `index.php`.  In other words, you can't have valid HTML with `<html></html>`, `<head></head>`, and `<body></body>` tags inside of a `<div>`.

Move your CSS to your global CSS file or the `head` of `index.php`, and your `map.php` page should contain *only* the following:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // google map code
    function initMap() { // etc.
        ....
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Will do. Right now Im not really sure how i will refactor my map.php to run the javascript (with bits of php code) without the html tags

Comment: @user1994644, see my edits.  The code, when it's loaded into `div2`, will end up _inside_ of `html` and `body` tags that already belong to `index.php`.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I still cant get the map to show. I edited my OP to show the code.

Comment: @user1994644, Please do a better job explaining exactly what you're showing us.  Is that the code for the new `map.php` page?  What does the _rendered_ HTML inside `div2` look like?  Is everything in there that you expect to be there?  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?  Is `initMap()` even being called?  All I can tell you is that you need to initialize your Google Map ***after*** you load your Google Map code into the page.  It should be that simple.  Is `div2` hidden on `index.php`?  A Google Map cannot be rendered inside a hidden element.

Comment: @user1994644, I went back a looked at one of your comments on your OP where you show the `load` just before the end of `body`.  Why are you using `ajax` to load content into `div2`?  Why not just put all the content into `div2` in the first place?

Comment: Yes I added the code for the new map.php page. I'm embarrassed that I can't answer your questions, but I'm working on it, now installing Firebug. Will get back to you in a few. Oh no, div2 is not hidden. Thanks

Comment: Im using ajax to load another php page to div1. My console says nothing's wrong with the script. apparently my database is the problem. it closes because I called the function multiple times in the other divs

Comment: @user1994644, very glad you got it sorted out.